# Find a value from a hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, collections, hashtable

If I were having a Generic list I would have done some thing like this

```
myListOfObject.FindAll(x=>(x.IsRequired==false));
```

What if I need to do similar stuff in `Hashtable`? Copying to temporary `hashtable` and looping and comparing would be that last thing I would try :-(

Comment: Don't use HashTables anymore if you're using > .NET 1.1 (in 99.999999%). Use strong type Dictionaries instead.

Comment: Hashtable h;  h.ContainsKey(YourKeyHere) or h.ContainsValue(YourValueHere)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, use `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for better strong-type support as opposed to `Hashtable`.

If you need to just find one key or one value, use the methods `ContainsKey(object key)` or `ContainsValue(object value)`, both of which are found on the `Hashtable` type.

Or you can go further and use linq extensions on the `Hashtable` parts:

```
Hashtable t = new Hashtable();
t.Add("Key", "Adam");

// Get the key/value entries.
var itemEntry = t.OfType<DictionaryEntry>().Where(de => (de.Value as string) == "Adam");

// Get just the values.
var items = t.Values.OfType<string>().Where(s => s == "Adam");

// Get just the keys.
var itemKey = t.Keys.OfType<string>().Where(k => k == "Key");
```