# How to insert and search a generic Hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, hashtable

Hello everyone i need some help :( i need someone to volunteer and show me how to implement an insert method and a search method on a generic HashTable in C#

I have tried multiple ways to implement this but non worked for me...

I need the add method to use the hashkey method to generate the key/index and account for quadratic probing.
And the find method to return the index the item is found at, or -1 if it isn't found

```
    class HashTable<T>
    {
        private T[] hasharray;

        public HashTable(int size)
        { hasharray = new T[size]; }

        public void Add(T value)
        {

            
        }

        private int find(T value)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        public static int hashkey(T value)
        {
            return value.ToString().Length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would typically use the built in dictionary. Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a value from a hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293827/find-a-value-from-a-hashtable)